# Converting a for loop into a while loop with post-increment

Tags: c

What would be the equivalent of doing the following `for` loop as a `while` loop?

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    ...
}
```

At first I thought the following would work:

```
int n = 0;
while (n++ <= 10) 
{
    ...
}
```

But it seems that the post-increment happens before the first while loop is entered, and so I'd need to set `n=-1` to adjust for that. Is there a closer way to re-write a `for` loop into a `while` loop (without the `do`) ?

Comment: do is a while loop, use that.

Comment: Not for the forward loop, though `int n = 10; while(n--) {...}` will work in reverse. However, any such rewrite will extend the scope and lifetime of `n` beyond the loops.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to put the increment *inside* the body of the loop (at the very end thereof):

```c
int n = 0;
while (n < 10) 
{
    //...
    n++;
}
```

**But note well**: As mentioned in the comments, any `continue` statement inside such a loop (if not itself enclosed in a nested, inner loop) will break the code and create a potentially infinite loop!

*Moral of the Story:* Use a `for` loop when a `for` loop is appropriate, and a `while` loop when a `while` loop is appropriate.

Comment: With the caveat that any accidental `continue;` would make it an infinite loop.

Comment: @dxiv Very good point. In fact, even a *deliberate* `continue` would do the same!

Answer (score 1):

There's two way to do it.

1. while loop
2. do-while loop

Try following source code

```
int n=0;
while(n <= 10){
      //do your task here
      n++;
}
```

do-while

```
int n=0;
do{
      //do your task here
      n++;
}while(n <= 10)
```

Comment: Both loops go too far by one. And anyway the OP asked for no `do`. If you are to use it then `int n=0; do {...} while(n++ < 10)` works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a post-increment while loop then use (n - 1) inside the while loop or you can create a temporary variable too.

```
int n = 0;
while(n++ < 10){
   // use n - 1
}
```

or,

```
int n = 0;
while(n++ < 10){
   int tn = n - 1; // use tn instead of n - 1
}
```